# CSS drop down menu not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I dont know why is this not working ? I am trying to make a drop down menu and when I hovering over it its not showing up.

CSS

```
#nav-line2 #dropmenu
{position:absolute;
display:none;
z-index:999;
list-style:none;
margin-left:450px}

#about:hover #nav-line2 #dropmenu{display:block;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav-line2" style="float:left">
<a class="navlink" id="about" href="/about">about</a>
<div id="dropmenu">
<li><a class="navlink" href="/aboutacc">Board of Directors</a></li>
<li><a class="navlink" href="/governance">Structure &amp; Governance</a></li>
</div>
<a class="navlink" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For starters, your markup is invalid.  You are missing a closing `div` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go backwards up the DOM tree with CSS selectors.  What you have is a selector that is looking for `#dropmenu` as a child of `#nav-line2` as a child of `#about`.  This selector should get you what you need:

```
#about:hover + #dropmenu {
    display:block;
}
```

It's the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Comment: you are a big life saver. Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make like a padding area so that drop down menu stays open when hovering.

Comment: @SoftDev  You should probably make that its own question; but to give you a general overview of what you need to do, you should change your margin to padding (margin doesn't trigger hover events), add to your selector to include the hover pseudo class for the `#dropmenu` itself (e.g. `#about:hover + #dropmenu, #dropmenu:hover`), and remove the `#nav-line2` part of your first selector (it adds too much specificity making the `#dropmenu:hover` selector ineffective). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XBCW2/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7D5c/)

```
<ul id="nav-line2">
<li><a class="navlink" id="about" href="/about">about</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
       <li><a class="navlink" href="/aboutacc">Board of Directors</a></li>
      <li><a class="navlink" href="/governance">Structure &amp; Governance</a></li>        
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a class="navlink" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
 </li>
 </ul>


ul#nav-line2 li {
position:relative;
list-style-type:none;
float: left;
padding:0px;
width: 125px;
height: 25px;
}
ul#dropdown {
position:absolute;
left:0;
width:125px;
visibility: hidden;
}
ul#nav-line2 li:hover #dropdown {
visibility:visible;
}
```

changed your structure slightly to include more UL, LI elements, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This HTML markup is standard format for dropdown menu Use always same structure to code Navigation Check this below jsfiddle example:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mystudies/tGd2k/)

```
<style>
ul.menu{height:40px;}
ul.menu li{float:left; width:auto;list-style:none;border:1px solid #ccc; position:relative;}
ul.menu li a{display:block; padding:10px;}

ul.menu li ul.subMenu{
background:#ccc;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:40px;
z-index:999;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
width:120px;
display:none;
}
ul.menu li ul li{ display:block; width:100%;}
ul.menu li ul li:hover{background:red;}
ul.menu li:hover ul.subMenu{display:block;}
</style>

<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>

</ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```